# ActiveAttr ":default" is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

ActiveAttr ":default" is not working for some reason.  I'm using it in Rails.  The "attributes" seem to get created, but the "defaults don't seem to get applied.

Code:

```
class Weekends
  include ActiveAttr::Model
  attribute :weeks, :default => ["asdf","qwer"]
  attribute :a, :default => "asdf;lkj" 
end
```

Console:

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:googleweekends greg$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
1.9.3-p0 :001 > w = Weekends.new
 => #<Weekends a: nil, weeks: nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute defaults support is only in active_attr v0.5.0+ which is currently in alpha. You can either install the prerelease from Rubygems.org or with git from github.com.

Comment: Your latest fixed has broken active_attr for jruby platform

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell from the documentation what functionality is included with ActiveAttr::Model, but you might also need to `include ActiveAttr::AttributeDefaults`

> Including the AttributeDefaults module into your class builds on
>   Attributes by allowing defaults to be declared with attributes.

```
class Person
  include ActiveAttr::AttributeDefaults

  attribute :first_name, :default => "John"
  attribute :last_name, :default => "Doe"
end

person = Person.new
person.first_name #=> "John"
person.last_name #=> "Doe"
```

Comment: get " uninitialized constant ActiveAttr::AttributeDefaults (NameError)" when I try this actually

Comment: Just dug around in the source and it looks like it's included with ActiveAttr::Model anyway so this wouldn't have done anything.